# Python with MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to write a function where I can pass in a variable (when the function is called) and this variable can somehow be passed into a MYSQL statement.

I am able to do that when the i need to add values to a table but when using a variable to name the table, it does not work.

Please check the a piece of the code below:

Many thanks 
K

```
def __init__(self): 
    self.connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                    user='root',
                                    password='Mandy123',
                                    db='connectiontest',
                                    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    self.mycursor = self.connection.cursor()

def create_table(self, name): 
    sql = (
       "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (%S) "
       "(id int auto_increment primary key, date date, "
       " open float, high float, low float, close float, "
       " volume float)"
       )
    self.mycursor.execute(sql)
    self.connection.commit()

name= input('what is the sql table name ? ')   
db= sql_manager()

db.create_table(name)
```

Comment: The variable `name` doesn't get put in the SQL statement anywhere.  Also  be careful with what the user puts in for `name` when you do get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't appear to use `name` in `create_table` at all. Secondly, you can't parameterise table names like this. You would need to use something like `format` to insert the table name e.g. `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}".format(name)` etc. and, depending on where this input comes from, you'd need to sanitise this input.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is easy :)

You have two options, however I would recommend you to use a string format function.

```
def create_table(self, name): 
     # you can use multiline string """ which makes it easier to read.
     # notice {0}. That is a place you want to insert first value passed to 'format' function.
    sql = (
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ({0})
        (id int auto_increment primary key, date date,
         open float, high float, low float, close float,
         volume float)"
        """.format(name)
       )
    self.mycursor.execute(sql)
    self.connection.commit()
```

Look here for more idead. [% vs format](https://pyformat.info/)